# JSDOC - JS How do I overload a method?

Tags: javascript, intellisense, jsdoc, typing

I'm struggling to document an overload to a method, though it works fine for object.

**This works**:

```
const test = {
    /** 
     * @type {{
     * (bar: string) => boolean
     * (bar: number) => string
     * }} 
     * */
    foo: (bar) => {
        // something...
    }
}
```

[image: Code with working intellisense]

**Doesn't work:**

```
class Test {
    /** 
     * @type {{
     * (bar: string) => boolean
     * (bar: number) => string
     * }} 
     * */
    foo(bar) {
        // something...
    }
}
```

[image: Code with not working intellisense]

Comment: looks like a bug since the return value looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript 5 introduces a new `@overload` tag, so you will be able to do something like:

```js
class Test {
    /** 
     * @overload
     * @param {string} bar
     * @returns {boolean}
     *
     * @overload
     * @param {number} bar
     * @returns {string}
     *
     * @param {string | number} bar
     * @returns {boolean | string}
     */
    foo(bar) {
        // something...
    }
}
```

See:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0-beta/#overload-support-in-jsdoc

Comment: Nice. I hope this will be introduced in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html) soon.